# How to build a Linux-based SMTP plugin

Tags: ruby, plugins, smtp

I'm looking for advice on how to develop a particular solution that relies on interacting with an SMTP server. Essentially, I want to have an SMTP server setup that receives all incoming email, parses the credentials and interacts with a server-based application (written in Ruby). That application can send back a response and the SMTP server will forward the message on.

In details, I'm looking for something that is:

- a plugin (a script, or an application) that works with any high-quality Linux-based SMTP server — Postfix, QMail, Sendmail, etc.
- a plugin that performs the following actions:

  - pulls authentication from incoming SMTP requests, posts that to a server-side application
  - receives a true or false response, either accepting or rejecting the message
  - on accept, pulls the recipients, subject and body, and posts that to the server-side application
  - receives a modified message body, replaces email message
  - forwards message on to ultimate destination

I'm at the stage where I don't even really know what I'm looking for. Is it something that can be strung together with Postfix's configuration directives? Is procmail somehow a part of this? Do I need a developer to write a full-blown plugin to some SMTP server? I'm familiar with administering these applications, but not development.

All insights and pointers appreciated!